# SBT Plugin Where is %%% defined?

Tags: scala, dependencies, scala.js, sbt-plugin

I have an SBT plugin which will auto-generate some Scala.js code just before compile time.  This code depends on a library which I would like to automatically include when the plugin is enabled.

This compiles and runs, but does not get the Scala.js version of the library:

```
import sbt._
import Keys.libraryDependencies

object MyPlugin extends AutoPlugin {
  object autoImport {
    lazy val baseSettings: Seq[Def.Setting[_]] = Seq(
      libraryDependencies += "my.lib" %% "library" % "0.1.0"
    )
  }

  import autoImport._

  override lazy val projectSettings = baseSettings
}
```

I when I try to use `"my.lib" %%% "library" % "0.1.0"`, I get:

```
value %%% is not a member of String
```

I feel like I'm probably missing an import, but I can't find where this is supposed to be defined.

Comment: Because there is nothing like `%%%`. There are only `%%` and `%`.

Comment: The scala.js documentation seems pretty clear to me.  Do you know something I don't?  https://www.scala-js.org/doc/project/dependencies.html

Comment: I meant that you are using only `%%` and `%` in you code - `libraryDependencies += "my.lib" %% "library" % "0.1.0"`. Sorry to misunderstand your questions.

Comment: Because when I replace that line with `libraryDependencies += "my.lib" %% "library" % "0.1.0"` I get an error.  I want to know what I need to import to make `%%%` work correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%%%` is defined by [the sbt-platformdeps plugin](https://github.com/portable-scala/sbt-platform-deps).

Unless your sbt plugin already depends on sbt-scalajs, you'll need to add a dependency to it in your plugin project's `settings`:

```
addSbtPlugin("org.portable-scala" % "sbt-platform-deps" % "1.0.0")
```

The following import will bring it in scope:

```
import org.portablescala.sbtplatformdeps.PlatformDepsPlugin.autoImport._
```

Comment: Thank you for you very concise and informative explanation.  I guess I was looking for it in the Scala.js code because I didn't realize it's a more general purpose syntax.

Answer (score -1):

addSbtPlugin("com.lightbend.lagom" % "lagom-sbt-plugin" % "X.Y.Z") // replace 'X.Y.Z' with your preferred version (e.g. '1.2.0-RC2').

You can refer to this one
https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.6.x/java/LagomBuild.html